# if url is mywebsite.com/url do something

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I am using WordPress to set a cookie for a specified page , but it can't be done by adding the php code on the page as with PHP, cookies are set in the web page header lines, before any page content is processed.

I found a solution and it's to edit the index.php file and adding the code in the top , but this will add the code for the all pages .

So i want a php code that will get the webpage url 
for example

```
if ($pageUrl == 'http://website.com/another_page')
 {
setcookie("cookie[one]","cookieone" , time()+3600*720); 
if (isset($_COOKIE["cookie"]))  
{
header("Location: http://website.com/page");
  } 
}
```

PS: The code above maybe broken .

Comment: yes, it's totally broken: syntax errors, logic errors.

Comment: I just want to know how to add a code when the page url is www.mywebsite.com/page/1/blog by adding a code in the index.php file

Comment: `http://website.com/page";);` should read as `http://website.com/page");` plus your conditional statement; wrong. Use another `=` - you're presently assigning to.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Edited ,  can you answer the question please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === "/page/1/blog"){
  // do code here
}
```

Request URI will give you the current URL after the domain name.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

    $message = ($actual_link == "http://localhost/SO/URI/") ? "Works" : "Doesn't work";
    echo $message;
?>
```

Works just fine when I test it locally.

Comment: You got a small problem with your code I tested it but it didn't work . it worked when I added / before [REQUEST_URI]